# C# Create symlink through bash does nothing

Tags: c#, bash, command-line, symlink

I found this function to run any command through bash from C#. So I tried passing it a command to create a symlink, but it's not doing anything. If I run that same command directly in a Terminal, it works. I tried running other commands like "ls" and that printed the proper items. Why isn't the symlink command working?

```
string output = ExecuteBashCommand("ln -s \"/Users/tim/academy-v2/Shared/Client Code\" \"/Users/tim/academy-v2/Shared Assets/Assets/Shared Code/Client Code\"");
UnityEngine.Debug.Log(output); // Prints "" like it worked, but didn't actually do anything.
```

...

```
static string ExecuteBashCommand(string command)
{
    command = command.Replace("\"", "\"\"");

    var proc = new Process
    {
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = "/bin/bash",
            Arguments = "-c \"" + command + "\"",
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        }
    };

    proc.Start();
    proc.WaitForExit();

    return proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
}
```

Comment: what about redirectstandarderror

Comment: Are you running your C# app _elevated_?

Comment: Elevated? Is that like running in admin mode on Windows? (I'm new to Mac)
I'm running this code in the Unity editor.

Comment: Hm, thanks for the tip. Redirecting the error printed: `ln: Code: No such file or directory`. How can I debug this?

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the command with this seems to work, though not sure why.

```
"ln -s /Users/tim/academy-v2/Shared/Client\\ Code /Users/tim/academy-v2/Shared\\ Assets/Assets/Shared\\ Code/Client\\ Code"
```